# TextViews not showing Android XML

Tags: android, xml

Can I get extra pair of eyes to look at this I can't get why the text views are not showing, I've spent hours rearranging everything and nothing seems to get them showing, I've looked at a lot of other people having the same issue and can't pin point the problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_default"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Member Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </EditText>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_default"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/relationships"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </Spinner>
    <com.special.utils.UITabs
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Male"
            style="@style/UITabs" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Female"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/UITabs" />

    </com.special.utils.UITabs>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        style="@style/UIButtonInverse"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm"
        style="@style/UIButtonInverse"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btncancel" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Birthday" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_default"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Head of Household Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:entries="@array/education"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </Spinner>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="In School?"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <com.special.utils.UITabs
            android:id="@+id/toggle3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                style="@style/UITabs" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="No"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                style="@style/UITabs"
                />

        </com.special.utils.UITabs>

        </LinearLayout>


    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Divide and conquer!  Comment-out stuff till it becomes more obvious.

Comment: Temporarily set the background colours of your view groups, e.g. LinearLayout, so that you can see exactly how they lay out.